# Unable to start new rails project - incompatible library version

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5

I just installed a new app with rails new crm
after bundle install and rails s i am unable to start server.

rails version is 5.2.3 ruby is 2.5.1

I'm stuck on how to fix this. Can someone please help me?

> /Users/MyName/.gem/ruby/2.5.1/gems/pg-1.1.4/lib/pg.rb:4:in `require':
>   incompatible library version -
>   /Users/MyName/.gem/ruby/2.5.1/gems/pg-1.1.4/lib/pg_ext.bundle
>   (LoadError)

Answer (score 1):

Try below step it should solv the issue

rvm gemset empty

gem install bundler

bundle install